# How to make forms for many-to-many self joins in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I hit submit on this form, I get "Dependency must exist" and "Dependent must exist":

```
<%= form.label :dependency_ids, "Dependencies" %><br />
<%= form.collection_select :dependency_ids, Article.order(:title),  :id, :title, {}, {multiple: true} %>

<%= form.label :dependent_ids, "Dependencies" %><br />
<%= form.collection_select :dependent_ids, Article.order(:title), :id, :title, {}, {multiple: true} %>
```

This is not because I failed to whitelist `:dependency_id` and `:dependent_id` in relations controller:

```
def relation_params
  params.require(:relation).permit(:dependency_id, :dependent_id)
end
```

The autogenerated form "works", in the sense that it actually saves the relation, but I have to type in the numbers:

```
<%= form.label :dependency_id %>
<%= form.number_field :dependency_id, id: :relation_dependency_id %>

<%= form.label :dependent_id %>
<%= form.number_field :dependent_id, id: :relation_dependent_id %>
```

Comment: In the first form you allow multiple:true (and pass an array of ids as parameter). In the second, you only allow one number. So both forms are different and pass different parameters to the controller. How do you handle the arrays you receive in the first form? Can you post your models and controller?

Comment: `dependency_ids` or `dependency_id` ? (you have both the pluralised and unpluralised versions in your code - pick the right one and use it in all the places)

Comment: I solved the problem now thanks to both your comments, by deleting "multiple: true" and using the unpluralised version. Thanks.